# Drupal 8 make a link with dynamic url paraneter without coding

Tags: hyperlink, drupal-8, dynamic-url, drupal-contextual-filters

I created two separate content types: "Clients" and "Injuries".
In "Clients" each record/node has a `client_id` (autoincrement by module Serial). In "Injuries" there is a field `client` which refers to `client_id`.

I created a (block) View for Injuries, with a contextual filter "Content: Client" so that I can filter out all the injuries of a specific client (for example: client_id = 3), just by typing the URI: /injuries/3.

Now I'm trying to create a link on the Client's page, which dynamically uses the `client_id` of that client. I tried the module "Linkit" and "D8 Editor Advanced Link".

Is there a way to get the client_id value of the node and use it in the URI?

I also try to make the link in a table view. Unlike the "edit-link" and the "view-link" which are in core, there's no way to customize the path in there.

Can anyone help pointing me in the right direction? Can I make it with the UI of Drupal 8 or do I have to dive into code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a token based field for your `client` content type using [field_token_value](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_token_value) module.

You create this field as usual and in the settings `field value` should be something like this

```
<a href="/injuries/[node:field_client_id]">see all injuries</a>
```

where `[node:field_client_id]` would be replaced with the appropriate `client_id` each time.

[image]

NOTE: There is also a link on the settings page that you can also display all available tokens

Comment: Thank you Giorgos. I'll try it.